# python sklearn features selection mutual_info_regression

Tags: python, feature-selection, sklearn-pandas

In `mutual_info_regression` pre-installed `n_neighbors=3`
This code works for `n_neighbors=3`:

```
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k='all').fit(X, y)
```

That request for `n_neighbors=2` in `mutual_info_regression`?

Don't work variants:

```
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression, k='all').fit(X, y,**{'n_neighbors':2})
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression(**{'n_neighbors':2}), k='all').fit(X, y)
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression(n_neighbors=2), k='all').fit(X, y)
selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_regression,n_neighbors=2, k='all').fit(X, y)

scoring = make_scorer(mutual_info_regression, greater_is_better=True, n_neighbors = 2)

selector = SelectKBest(scoring, k='all').fit(feat, targ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pythons `partial` function to create a scorer with non-default values:

```
from functools import partial
scorer_function = partial(mutual_info_regression, n_neighbors=2)
selector = SelectKBest(scorer_function, k='all').fit(X, y)
```